# Trouble opening certain attachments /links via the BlackBerry browser

Tags: html, blackberry, java-me

I'm having trouble opening certain attachments/links through the BlackBerry browser.

```
works = opens in correct app.

5.0-9700
PDF-works
TXT-works
HTML-works
DOC-works
JPG-works
RTF-fails (goes to save)
DOCX-fails (500 server error)

6.0-9800
PDF-works
TXT-works
HTML-works
DOC-fails (goes to save)
JPG-works
RTF-fails (goes to save)
DOCX-fails (goes to save)
```

I'm opening these attachments through the browser via the following code:

```
BrowserSession bSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
bSession.displayPage(urlForAttachment);
```

Both of these devices are connected to a BES.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue so that all of the attachments/links open correctly through the browser?

**Update 2 Feb 2011:**

So in 5.0 it was an MIME settings issue.  Here are the correct settings on the server:

```
docx = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
doc  = application/msword
```

In 6.0 it seems to be a browser issue.  When we upgraded to a new build of 6.0, here is the error we got:

> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> Sorry, we can't open the web page that you requested because access was denied. If you should have access to this web page, contact your wireless service provider.
>
> Error Code: 10001

Any ideas?

Note: the server doesn't even log an attempt to communicate.

Thanks!

Comment: Your 6.0 issue sounds like it is distinct from what you first posted.  I think you're better off posting a new question for that.

Comment: Your 6.0 issue should be posted on serverfault instead of stackoverflow, as it's not really about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the server is sending the correct content-type http header for the content.

It would also be more useful to show your works/fails table against the content-type values, instead of the file extensions.

Comment: If the header is wrong, why would it work for one browser and not the other?

Comment: http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB19814 .  I'm having this issue as well.  I'm betting they are related.

Comment: So what are the content-type headers for those files?

Comment: docx =a pplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: And all of this works great on 5.0. We're only having the issue on 6.0.